# How to include preamble-only commands in .dtx file?

Tags: preamble, dtx

I am trying to write my first package using Doc and DocStrip but I have problems including preamble-only commands into the documentation. For example I want to include `\allowdisplaybreaks` inside `\begin{macrocode} ... \end{macrocode}`. But then Doc seems to try to make the command available for the documentation and this fails since `\allowdisplaybreaks` is contained in the document part.

Is there a way to stop Doc from treating certain commands as macros which also should be available during the documentation?

EDIT: To make it more precise: this

```
%\begin{macro}{\allowdisplaybreaks}
% page breaks allowed in long formulas
%    \begin{macrocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
```

is part of my .dtx file, but when running it I get a "Undefined control sequence"-error, but it works if I replace `\allowdisplaybreaks` by some `\newcommand`.

EDIT 2: So here is package.dtx

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{package.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{package}
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{package}[2004/11/05]
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \DocInput{package.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi

%\begin{macro}{\allowdisplaybreaks}
% page breaks allowed in long formulas
%    \begin{macrocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

As stated above I get a "! Undefined control sequence.
l.24 \allowdisplaybreaks"-error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make a small code example of what you're trying to achieve (MWE)?

Comment: Assuming you have a driver, _etc._, you'll be fine. However, we will need some idea of the full structure of your `.dtx`.

Comment: you are only loading amsmath in the documentation driver and only using `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the package code. You need to add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the driver section and add `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` to your package code.

Comment: @JosephWright : I added a (hopefully extensive enough) code example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the documentation, but if you want to allow display breaks in the doc, you need to add it. Conversely if your package code is using `\allowdisplaybreaks` then it probably should have `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{package.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{package}
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usep*ackage{package}[2004/11/05]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
    \DocInput{package.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%\begin{macro}{\allowdisplaybreaks}
% page breaks allowed in long formulas
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
% \Finale
\endinput
```